# Cannot extend class unless i remove its constructor

Tags: php, oop

These are my first steps in OOP php.

I have this class in my CMS.

```
class Pages
{
 private static $oInstance = null;
  public static function getInstance( ){
    if( !isset( self::$oInstance ) ){  
      self::$oInstance = new Pages( );  
    }  
    return self::$oInstance;  
  } // end function getInstance

  /**
  * Constructor
  * @return void
  */
  private function __construct( ){
    $this->generateCache( );
  } // end function __construct

  /**
  * Generates cache variables
  * @return void
  */
  public function generateCache( ){
    //some more code

}
};
```

I want to create my class extending `Pages` to make use of its properties and methods:

```
class New extends Pages{

 private static $oInstance = null;
 public static function getInstance( ){
 if( !isset( self::$oInstance ) ){  
   self::$oInstance = new Ajax( );  
}  
 return self::$oInstance;  
} 

public function newmethod(){

//some logic
}
};
```

However when i attempt to initialize Object, php just generates blank page (even without error).

```
$object = New::getInstance( );
```

or

```
$object = new New();
```

What am I doing wrong?
If I remove constructor from parent and child class at lest page renders.

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851

Comment: Try changing your constructor to a protected method instead of private. Private methods cannot be used by sub classes.

Answer (score 3):

The class `New` does not declare a constructor. This means it inherits the constructor from the base class. But the constructor of the base class is [`private`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) and that restricts its usage to the methods of its class.

The solution is to declare the constructor of class `Pages` as [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). This way it can be called by the methods of the derived classes.

More, if a class is not declared as [`final`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) (this prevents extending it) then it must not declare its constructor as `private`. Having the constructor private prevents the constructor of the children classes to call it and this lets the properties of the base class uninitialized (i.e. the objects of the derived classes are not properly constructed).

Declaring the constructor as `private` is a bad practice. It requires having a static method of the class that acts as a factory of objects of that class (the method `getInstance()` in your case) and this makes the class difficult to test and impossible to replace with a mock in a test.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in your New-class you mean

```
self::$oInstance = new New( );
```

Comment: Yup, forgot to change this.

Comment: Yes, thought that was the problem and solution. Please update your question and i delete my answer.